# pip install numpy not working in virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I'm having a weird problem with Python 2.7
When I run `pip install numpy` inside a virtualenv, it reports success:

```
  Added numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/37/fe7db552f4507f379d81dcb78e58e05030a8941757b1f664517d581b5553/numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylin
ux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=0df89ca13c25eaa1621a3f09af4c8ba20da849692dcae184cb55e80952c453fb to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-3MfIdU'
  Removed numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/37/fe7db552f4507f379d81dcb78e58e05030a8941757b1f664517d581b5553/numpy-1.15.4-cp27-cp27mu-manyl
inux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=0df89ca13c25eaa1621a3f09af4c8ba20da849692dcae184cb55e80952c453fb from build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-3MfIdU'
Installing collected packages: numpy

Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-3MfIdU'
```

But then the package is not there with `pip list` and not available for import:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        18.1   
setuptools 40.6.3 
wheel      0.32.3
```

it *does* work in the global context outside venv, and I'm not having the problem in venv with other packages.

I double-checked that `pip` is pointing to the pip binary in the virtualenv/bin folder.

Comment: Can you share the console of your installation and your `pip list` result?

Comment: Do you have a file named `numpy.py` in the Python path?

Comment: No, no `numpy.py` in my venv anywhere and not in my regular path either.

Comment: Just to double-check, if you do a `pip freeze`, `numpy` is in the list? Also, are you able to import `numpy` if you run Python in the console?